# Find existing Jobs in an Eclipse RCP 4 application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have some long running tasks in my eclipse RCP (e4) application that I implemented using the Job API. The Job is started immediately (before GUI is shown).

```
private class MyJob extends Job {

@Override
protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    monitor.beginTask("do some long stuff", 4);

    doStep1();
    monitor.worked(1);
    doStep2();
    monitor.worked(1);
    doStep3();
    monitor.done();
}
// methods for the steps follow here
}
```

Now I want to display a progress bar somewhere in my GUI to show if MyJob is still running.

I have tried this using the IJobManager:

```
public class MyStatusbar {
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Inject
UISynchronize sync;

@PostConstruct
public void createControls(Composite parent) {
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(parent, SWT.SMOOTH);
    progressBar.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 20);

    // Setting the progress monitor
    IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();

    final IProgressMonitor p = (IProgressMonitor) new IProgressMonitor() {

        @Override
        public void worked(final int work) {
            sync.syncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Worked");
                    progressBar.setSelection(progressBar.getSelection()
                            + work);
                }
            });
        }

        // [...]
    };
    ProgressProvider provider = new ProgressProvider() {
        @Override
        public IProgressMonitor createMonitor(Job job) {
            return p;
        }
    };

    manager.setProgressProvider(provider);
}
}
```

But my Job is not shown in the status bar. I suppose it has something to do with my starting the job before the GUI is there but I'm not sure.

So I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is my approach correct or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to create the progress monitor and call `IJobManager.setProgressProvider` before the `Job` starts (which is when `ProgressProvider.createMonitor` is called).

I set up my progress provider in the `@PostContextCreate` method of my `LifeCycle` class.